# Is “malheureuse” in this sentence a noun?

Tags: adjectifs, noms

[image]

The little girl smurf is made of an explosive composition so Gargamel is afraid of her. So, is it a noun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit du substantif ; Le TLFi cerne assez bien le contexte d'utilisation dans sa définition, laquelle suit ;

> [[employé]] exclamativement. Qui marque la colère, l'indignation contre quelqu'un.
>
> - Petit malheureux! Comment, malheureux, vous n'avez pas l'ordre écrit? Alors qu'avez-vous à nous montrer?

Dans le contexte de cette bande dessinée c'est une exclamation de colère.

Le dictionnaire de l'Académie précise que l'utilisation de cette exclamation peut indiquer de la surprise et de la réprobation. De plus, il indique qu'elle n'est pas très utilisé de nos jours (vieilli).

> S'emploie en apostrophe pour exprimer à quelqu'un la surprise, la réprobation, la colère, le dépit (vieilli).
>
> - Malheureux ! Qu'as-tu fait ?

De nos jours des énoncés plus longs et plus expressifs sont utilisés pour remplacer cette exclamation et ils sont particuliers à un contexte donné : on ne peut pas les employer généralement ; il prennent parfois la forme d'une question mais ne sont pas réellement des questions et leur ton est assez exclamatif ; quelques uns sont mentionnés ci-dessous.

- Qu'est-ce que vous avez fait là ?/Qu'est-ce que tu as fait là ?
- Quelle idée d'avoir fait ça !
- Qu'est-ce qui vous a pris ?/Qu'est-ce qui t'a pris ?

Answer (score 0):

*malheureux* - adj - unfortunate

Example [French language](https://www.rosettastone.com/french-language) / sentences Including 'malheureux'

- *Il est malheureux que la Commission n'en ait donné aucune indication,
  et que la Cour des comptes n'ait rien dit non plus.*

> It is unfortunate that the Commission has given no indication of this,
>   and that the Court of Auditors, for that matter, has not mentioned it
>   either.

- *Dans certains cas, ils n'arrivent pas à vendre leurs produits, ce qui
  est malheureux parce que la récolte de cette année est exceptionnelle
  pour toutes les cultures.*

> In some cases, they can't sell their produce (which) is a shame,
>   because this has been an extremely good year for all crops.

Comment: Dans le contexte de la question, il s'agit d'un substantif, pas d'un adjectif.

Comment: « In some cases, they can't sell their produce, which is a shame, …» is the usual form ; is that form without « which » a recently accepted grammatical turn?